# Does global variable have access inside arrow function?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
productDetails = await page.$$eval(inputData.PRODUCTS_LIST, 
productsList => productsList.map(productList => ({
                productName : productList.querySelector('.product-details--content > h3').innerText
                }))
        )
```

inputData is the global variable. I want to use inputData.ProductName in place of '.product-details--content > h3'. But it shows inputData is undefined.

Ex:

```
productDetails = await page.$$eval(inputData.PRODUCTS_LIST, 
productsList => productsList.map(productList => ({
                productName : productList.querySelector(inputData.PRODUCTS_NAME).innerText
                }))
        )
```

Can anyone please to find out the mistake I'm doing and please tell the right syntax to use global variable inside the arrow function

Answer (score 4):

The `page.$$eval` function executes code in the context of the browser and then return the result to the node context.

The problem here is that the browser cannot see the global context of node, since it have its own global context, this is why you pass the variable to the browser as argument in the `page.$$eval` function.

Don't forget that when you're dealing with puppeteer, you are working with 2 contexts.

The first argument on the `page.$$eval()` function is always a selector you want to get from the DOM tree.

The second argument is the callback you want to execute in the browser context.

The third, and optional, argument is the parameters you want to pass to your callback.

So, if you want the browser to have access to the `inputData` variable, you will have to pass it on the third argument. Something like this, i suppose:

```js
productDetails = page.$$eval(inputData.PRODUCTS_LIST, (productsList) => productsList.map((productList) => ({
  productName: productList.querySelector(inputData.PRODUCTS_NAME).innerText,
})), inputData);
```

You can read more about evaluation on puppeteer [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args).

Comment: Thanks for your response @innis.. I have understood the contexts part.. And I tried passing the `inputData` has an optional argument to the `pageFunction` as per the syntax, Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If is a global variable defined with var it is accesible, in fact any variable is a property of this object. The problem seems to be that map use a Callback and this is asyncronous so in the time the function is executed the variable inputData probably doesn't exist because this has changed. Has you try using bind()?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Hey, David, thank you for participating! Alas, this is a puppeteer-specific question, so what you suggest will not work (see innis' answer why). But even not taking that into consideration, it would be very useful if you included a short code sample to illustrate your solution.